# How can I insert an info icon next to a text in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

How do I insert a green info icon on the right side where it says "Select the best number of bins". Can you help me?

I really appreciate the help!

I insert a executable code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
                        
                        
                        titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
                        
                        
                        sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(h4("Select the best the number of bins"),
                                         br(),
                                         br(),
                                sliderInput("bins",
                                            "Number of bins:",
                                            min = 1,
                                            max = 50,
                                            value = 30)
                            ),
                            
                            
                            mainPanel(
                                plotOutput("distPlot")
                            )
                        )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an icon with the `icon` function inside the `h4`. To change the color you can apply a custom CSS by using `style = "color: green"`.

```R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(h4("Select the best the number of bins", 
                      icon("info", style = "color: green")),
                   br(),
                   br(),
          sliderInput("bins",
                      "Number of bins:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = 50,
                      value = 30)
      ),
      mainPanel(
          plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Geovany.  Is it possible to put another shade of green?

Comment: instead of `green` you can use the hexadecimal color representation like `#00e800`. From there you can use any other color.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much Geovany! I asked a question earlier that I believe you can help. Can you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977633/change-color-of-a-shiny-theme